# how to recursively parse a comma separated string with nested parentheses

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I have comma separated input of graphs with each graph input starting and ending with braces () .Between the braces lies details of vertices and edges in set form as below

`({A,B,C},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)}),({A,B,C,D,E},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(E,D),(D,A)})`

this input string contains two graph:({V1,..}{(E1),..}),({V2,..}{(E2),..}),..

```
{A,B,C},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)}
{A,B,C,D,E},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(E,D),(D,A)}
```

Is there regex to parse this without too much of boilar plate code...?

Comment: You can recursively match using regex if the language supports it. However, the match will contain all the sub-nesting. This is not parsing. It takes extra steps, like a recursive function to parse each inner core. This would be all well and good using PCRE or Perl. Unfortunately Java doesn't support recursion in it's regex engine.

Comment: Time for ye olde state machine...

Comment: Is `{A,B,C},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)}` and `{A,B,C,D,E},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(E,D),(D,A)}` the expected output and does it **need** to be in regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `while(matcher.find())` loop to match all the occurrences of graphs in your input, parsing the match into vertices and edges, fairly easily.

```
String data = "({A,B,C},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)}),({A,B,C,D,E},{(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(E,D),(D,A)})";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\{([^}]+)\\},\\{([^}]+)\\}\\)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Graph vertices=" + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("      edges=" + matcher.group(2));
}
```

Output:

```
Graph vertices=A,B,C
      edges=(A,B),(B,C),(C,A)
Graph vertices=A,B,C,D,E
      edges=(A,B),(B,C),(C,A),(E,D),(D,A)
```

Regex detail:

`"\(\{([^}]+)\},\{([^}]+)\}\)"` - expression, after `\\` to `\` source translation
`"\(\{       \},\{       \}\)"` - match literal `({    },{    })` characters
`"    (     )     (     )    "` - capturing groups 1 & 2
`"     [^}]+       [^}]+     "` - match 1 or more non `}` characters

`matcher.find()` will locate and capture the first match, and then subsequent matches, finally returning `false` when no more matches can be found.

Parsing of the vertex and edge data may be done in a similar fashion.  Left to student.

Comment: super genius...thanks Sir...this is more than what i ask for...i wish one day I could think like you...

Comment: for parsing edges we can loop on \(([^)]+),([^)]+)\)  similar to top level graph input as explained above

Comment: @MominFakhruddin Just keep working at it; experience is what is required, which is why I left you that *Left to student* part.  Unfortunately, you got it wrong.  For the first group, you are matching non-`)` characters, which will take you right of the end of the edge term; you want to stop at the `,`.  Plus, you need to *escape* the `()` characters you want treated as literal characters instead of capturing group delimiters.

Comment: yes, actually \ got auto-removed , I used `\(([^)]+),([^)]+)\)` , and it worked just fine for me

Comment: @MominFakhruddin It works, but so you know why: it is because of back-tracking.  `[^)]+` is greedy; it matches as much as possible, ending only when it encounters the `)` character.  Then, it tried to match the rest of the regex, and finds the next character (a `)`) does not match the expected character (a `,`).  So, the regex engine back-tracks one character, and then sees if it can match the rest of the regex, and keeps on back-tracking until it backtracks over the `,`.  Instead, your first match should be `[^,]+` which matches only until the comma.  `\(([^,]+),([^)]+)\)`

Comment: Alternately, for the edge data, you could use `\((\w+),(\w+)\)` which is a little simpler and clearer.  It matches `(Identifier_1,Identifier_2)`.